# Difficulties with RANKX function DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I face difficulties with applying the `RANKX` function.
The ranking in the example below should be dynamically modified by `Customer` in the Matrix Rows, `Year` in the Matrix Columns and  `Group`, `Year` and `Week` in the slicers. The ranking is based on the `Volume` measure shown herebelow.

**Issue:**

When all weeks are selected the ranking works fine, but whenever I filter on certain weeks the ranking shows double ranks. How can I solve this?

**The DAX I used:**

```
Rank = 
RANKX( ALL(Volume[Customer]), Volume[Volume],,DESC, Dense)
```

```
Volume = SUM(Volume[Total Volume])
```

**Screenshots of the matrix**

**1. Matrix when all weeks are selected, showing the right ranks**

[image: Matrix when all weeks are selected, showing the right ranks]

**2. Matrix when certain weeks are selected, showing wrong ranks**

[image: Matrix when certain weeks are selected, showing wrong ranks]

Comment: can you provide more details about your model? tables, columns, relationships and some sample data for each table?

Comment: It is just one table that I queried containing facts and dimensions, that's possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this below code-

```
Rank = 
RANKX( 
    ALLSELECTED(Volume[Customer]), 
    Volume[Volume],
    ,
    DESC, 
    
)
```

Comment: This unfortunately gives the exact same result

Comment: @Luukv93 can you just leave the Dense part blank and try as edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have a single table instead of a star schema there are cross-filtering effects. To remove these we must first remove the whole filtering, then apply back the desired filters from the visual and from the slicers.

```
Rank 1 =
VAR Customers =
    ALLSELECTED( Volume[Customer] )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE(
        RANKX( Customers, Volume[Volume],, DESC, DENSE ),
        REMOVEFILTERS( Volume ),
        VALUES( Volume[Year] ),
        VALUES( Volume[Customer] ),
        ALLSELECTED( Volume[Week] )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Since there are no slicers on Customer, we might also use ALL instead of ALLSELECTED

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with Sergio, the problem is caused by one table, so you need to remove the filters

```
REMOVEFILTERS( Volume ),
```

Then the values

```
VALUES( Volume[Year] ),
        VALUES( Volume[Customer] ),
        ALLSELECTED( Volume[Week] )
```